# STR instruction in ARM assembly doesn't work (using KEIL)

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, keil

I'm trying to store a value in memory. my code is here:

```
        TTL TEST
        global main

        AREA PROGRAM, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY

main
        ADR     R0, DATA
        MOV     R1, #5
        STR     R1, [R0]

HALT        B       HALT

DATA    DCD     10

        END
```

I'm using KEIL uvision4, and my target is STM32F407VGT microprocessor. While debugging code, nothing changes in memory windows. What's wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like you've placed your `DATA` variable in the `CODE` `AREA`, which is `READONLY`.

Comment: @Michael I don't know how to define separate areas in arm assembly. I've tried to add  "AREA programdata, DATA, READWRITE" just before DATA but it didn't work. I have changed "READONLY" to "READWRITE" but it didn't work for me either.

Comment: Then it's probably a good idea to read [the documentation for `AREA`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cacbjgcc.html).

Comment: @Michael I've read it many times! but it didn't help me to solve this problem! @_@

Answer (score 2):

This is a piece of code I rewrote from some earlier code of mine. (I didn't test it again)

```
   PRESERVE8
   TTL TEST
   global main

   AREA asectionname, DATA, READWRITE
DATA DCD 10

   AREA PROGRAM, CODE, READONLY
   ENTRY

main
   ADR  R0, DATA
   MOV  R1, #5
   STR  R1, [R0]

HALT 
   B    HALT
   END
```

By adding `AREA asectionname, DATA, READWRITE` the thereon following lines are going to be placed in a RAM area and is able to be read and written to. `DATA DCD 10` declares a variable called `DATA` which is the size of 1 word with the initial value of 10. (`DCD` allocates a full word, `DCB` alloctes a byte)

Please take a look at this [page](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361290001365.htm) for further pointers on what to do and how things work.

Comment: [The args to `DCD` are a list of values, not a size](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361290005934.htm).  `DCD 10` emits 1 word with value `10` (in the current AREA).